# Excel cell value as a .SetSourceData range

Tags: vba, excel

I m having an issue using cell values as the input for range of the `.SetSourceData` method.  My cell values are:

```
K6 = $C$95
K7 = $C$137
K8 = $F$95
K9 = $F$137
```

So, I would like create a new line-chart using the entries in K6 and K7 ($C$95 : $C$137) as the X values, and entries in K8 and K9 ($F$95 : $F$137) as the Y values.

If I hard-code the entries in the `.SetSourceData` range like this, it works:

```
.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Sheet1!$C$95:$C$137, Sheet1!$F$95:$F137")
```

but ive tried several different ways to try to use the value of the K cells as the range.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

PS
I could not get this to work:

```
Sub CreateChart()

Dim X1 As String
Dim X2 As String
Dim Y1 As String
Dim Y2 As String

X1 = "$C$95"
X2 = "$C$137"
Y1 = Range("K6").Value  'where the value in this cell is $F$95
Y2 = Range("K7").Value  'Where the value in this cell is $F$137



With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("Sheet1!" & .Range(X1).Value & ":" & .Range(X2).Value & ",Sheet1!" & .Range(Y1).Value & ":" & .Range(Y2).Value)
End With

ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine



End Sub
```

--

--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should start you off

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("Sheet1!" & .Range("K6").Value & ":" & .Range("K7").Value & _
                                      ",Sheet1!" & .Range("K8").Value & ":" & .Range("K9").Value)
End With
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
```

Second answer

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("Sheet1!" & X1 & ":" & X2 & ",Sheet1!" & Y1 & ":" & Y2)
```

Comment: Any idea on why this doesn't work?
`Sub CreateChart()`
`Dim X1 As String`
`Dim X2 As String`
`Dim Y1 As String`
`Dim Y2 As String`

`X1 = "C95"`
`X2 = "C137"`
`Y1 = Range("K6").Value`
`Y2 = Range("K7").Value`



`With Sheets("Sheet1")`
   ` .Shapes.AddChart.Select`
   ` ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("Sheet1!" & .Range(X1).Value & ":" & .Range(X2).Value & _`
`                                      ",Sheet1!" & .Range(Y1).Value & ":" & .Range(Y2).Value)`
`End With`

ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine

Comment: Does this work? `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range("Sheet1!" & .Range(X1).Value & ":" & .Range(X2).Value & ",Sheet1!" & .Range(Y1).Value & ":" & .Range(Y2).Value)`

Comment: Strangely it doesn't.  Its giving me the Run-time error '1004'.  I thought it would work because when i hover over the variables they appear to be the exact strings that are in your working response.

Comment: What's in K6 and K7?

Comment: $F$95 and $F$137

Comment: Can you add the code in the comment as a postscript to your question as it's hard to read?

Comment: OK, have added a "second answer" above which should solve that - was forgetting that the source data needs to be a string which equates to a valid range. Previously it was trying to use the contents of eg C95 rather than the string "C95" itself.